# Would one say "become one with shadow" this way, Hitotsu Ni Naru Kage (一つになる影)?

Tags: english-to-japanese

The closest I have been able to figure out, through google searches, how to write out the phrase "become one with shadow" is Hitotsu Ni Naru Kage (一つになる影). Is this correct? If not, how would one say this?

Comment: In regards to closing this question, I think that if we are going to hold a consistent standard of prior research and effort, this question got short changed.  The OP clearly did their own research on this problem, as a simple trip to google translate returns: https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=ja&text=become%20one%20with%20shadow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're pretty close, but not quite there.

一つになる影 is not `become one with shadow`.  The reason for this is because if you use the structure `verb (plain form) + noun`, the English equivalent is `noun that verbs.`  Here's an example:

> マラソンを走る人
> Person/people that run(s) marathons

Therefore, your attempt translates as follows:

> 一つになる影
> Shadow that becomes one.

What you need is a little bit of reordering, and a particle that means `with` as well.  In Japanese, that particle is と.  Simply put the と particle after a noun, and you get the result you seek.  Please note this is just one of several uses for the と particle, the other functions you will have to research separately.  So here's an example:

> **彼と**店に行く。
> Go **with him** to the store.

Extending these changes to your attempt yields:

> 影と一つになる
> Become one with (your) shadow.

Context here matters.  If you're talking about someone trying to hide in their shadow, the  'your' will be added in translation even though the Japanese doesn't change.  If you're talking about a ninja becoming one with shadow to infiltrate an enemy camp, the Japanese won't change, but the translation will reflect this.  As you study the Japanese language, you'll get a feel for what is and is not implied.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I found this extremely helpful. Would that mean Kage ni Nari 影になる would mean "become a shadow"?

Comment: I'm assuming that you initially meant to write kage ni *naru* instead of kage ni *nari* since your translation was correct.  There's no particular nuance here, so yeah.  "Become shadow" is my first thought of translation but you could insert a/the in there without any problems.  Depending on the rest of the sentence, you may insert a/the to make it flow better.